# Find element in a list and change it using stream()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to find an element in a `List`, change it or throw `Exception` if the element wasn't found, using Java 8 stream?

In other words, I would like to rewrite following code using `stream`. The best I could get is to change the item value, but no way to find out if an item was found/changed.

```
boolean isFound = false;
for (MyItem item : myList) {
    if (item.getValue() > 10) {
        item.setAnotherValue(5);
        isFound = true;
    }
}

if (!isFound) {
    throw new ElementNotFoundException("Element 10 wasn't found");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your goal is to only find a single element, you could do

```
MyItem item = l.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getValue() > 10)
                .findAny()  // here we get an Optional
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Element 10 wasn't found"));
        item.setAnotherValue(4);
```

In Java 9, using `ifPresentOrElse`, this can be somewhat simplified to (unfortunately the syntax `()->{throw new RuntimeException();}` is also a bit clumsy, but AFAIK it can't be simplified):

```
l.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getValue() > 10)
    .findAny() // here we get an Optional
    .ifPresentOrElse(x->x.setAnotherValue(5),
            ()->{throw new RuntimeException();});
```

If you want to do that for all items, you can try something like that. But as Java 8 Streams are not designed to operate via side effects, this it not a really clean approach:

```
AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);
l.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getValue() > 10)
        .forEach(x->{
            x.setAnotherValue(5);
            b.set(true);
        });
if (b.get()){
   throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Of course, you could also just simply collect the elements into a list and then do your operations. But I am not sure if this is any improvement over the simple for-loop you started with...

Well if `forEach` returned a `long` which represents the number of elements it was invoked on, this would be easier...

Comment: That `AtomicBoolean` solution looks awful. It’s more a task for `collect`: `boolean hadMatches = l.stream() .filter(x -> x.getValue() > 10) .collect(()->new boolean[1], (b,x)->{x.setAnotherValue(5);b[0]=true;}, (b1,b2)->b1[0]|=b2[0])[0];`

Comment: @Holger: well I guess neither solution is particularly elegant. Or do you think that there may be a problem with contention when using that `AtomicBoolean` with parallel streams?

Comment: In this case, it’s not contention (as all consumers are only writing rather than doing `cas`), but having a memory barrier between each element’s processing, hindering hotspot optimizations, which is even the case in the sequential execution, unless the optimizer figures out that this `AtomicBoolean` is purely local. The `collect` operation may not look very elegant, but is closely to what `mapping(x->{x.setAnotherValue(5); return true;}, reducing(false, Boolean::logicalOr))` would do. Oh wait, that might be the alternative…

Comment: Ok, then we can also use `.map(x->{x.setAnotherValue(5); return true;}) .reduce(false, Boolean::logicalOr);`. In either case, the side effect bearing action has to be placed somewhere…